# Master node had taint, other nodes did't match node affinity selector

Tags: kubernetes

Plz advice in my new work I faced very strage issue previous employee incorrectly deployed kubernetes cluster 2 years ago now some application crashed.

error:
 `Warning  FailedScheduling  4m33s (x86 over 105m)  default-scheduler  0/3 nodes are available: 1 node(s) had taint {node.kubernetes.io/disk-pressure: }, that the pod didn't tolerate, 2 node(s) didn't match Pod's node affinity/selector`

k**ubectl get nodes**

```bash
root@k8sc2m2:~# kubectl get nodes
NAME      STATUS   ROLES                  AGE    VERSION
k8sc2m1   Ready    control-plane,master   728d   v1.22.2
k8sc2m2   Ready    control-plane,master   728d   v1.22.2
k8sc2m3   Ready    control-plane,master   728d   v1.22.2
```

`k8sc2m1` have taint  `node.kubernetes.io/disk-pressure:NoSchedule`

Adding resource to `k8sc2m1` not option

I don't have .yaml of crashing app. When I restart pod giving error above

What to do in this situation?

Comment: which I have shared a document with you there is  information regarding Disk pressure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution in this case is Adding new disks space to avoind `taint` disk pressure

We did so, and problem gone

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting usually occurs when there is a taint on nodes for which the pod specification does not contain a corresponding toleration.

This issue may arrive sometimes if your nodes are not ready and if you have some custom taints.

**To resolve your issue either you need add taints to the workers node or remove the taints from the master node as mentioned below:**

**Add taint to the worker node,as per [Densify chapter 6 doc](https://www.densify.com/kubernetes-autoscaling/kubernetes-taints/)

Master nodes are already tainted by the Kubernetes default installation. So that no user pods land on them until intentionally configured by the user to be placed on master nodes by adding tolerations for those taints. Worker node that has no taints. We will now taint the worker so that only front-end pods can land on it. We can do this by using the kubectl taint command like below :

```
kubectl taint nodes cluster01-worker-1 app=frontend:NoSchedule node/cluster01-worker-1 tainted
```

**Remove taint from the Master node:**

Run the below commands to remove the taints from the masternode, which allows you to deploy your pod on that node. Refer to official kubernetes [doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#taint) for more info.

```
kubectl taint nodes <nodename\> [node-role.kubernetes.io/master-](http://node-role.kubernetes.io/master-)
```

or

```
 kubectl taint node master [node-role.kubernetes.io/master:NoSchedule-](http://node-role.kubernetes.io/master:NoSchedule-)
```

In order to find out why it's displaying as the master node, use kubeadm to join the node using the command you ran. The commands for joining the worker and master nodes are different.

**Note :**

To check for taints, run kubectl describe node <nodename>.

```
kubectl describe node <nodename\> \| grep Taints
```

This is what you will see if there is any taint on the node.

```
[node-role.kubernetes.io/master:NoSchedule](http://node-role.kubernetes.io/master:NoSchedule)
```

**Also check below yaml on how to schedule master node without removing the taint:**

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
... 
   Spec: 
...
   Spec: 
... 
    tolerations: 
      - key: "node-role.kubernetes.io/master"
        effect: "NoSchedule"
        operator: "Exists"
```

You can refer to this official [doc1](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/taint-and-toleration/)  and also [doc 2 w](https://pauldally.medium.com/one-common-reason-your-pod-may-be-stuck-in-pending-46bf3890915b)ritten by Paul Dally for more information about Taints and Tolerations.

Comment: When I remove taint from node, control plane(master node) automatically creating it